# Why is the head loss in submerged pipe is 0

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, pipelines

Looking at this question :

Point C head loss is 0 according to the author
Bottom right
Can’t understand why , any good explanation for this claim ?

Look at page 33 at the top
[image]

Comment: The only way for that to happen is : 


0 velocity at the top submerged pipe 

 zero pressure At the top submerged pipe

Comment: are you sure they mean the area of the outlet of pipe ( **C'** ) or maybe it's about the reservoir ( C )in general?

Comment: C in general because C’ is for another question relating to sudden cut of the pipe

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $H_{\mathsf{C}}$ here doesn't represent a head *loss*, it represents an "absolute" head at point $\mathsf{C}$.  Assuming that the fluid velocity in the region vertically above $\mathsf{C}$ is negligible, so that the pressure variation in that region is hydrostatic, that absolute head is equal to the vertical co-ordinate of the free surface above $\mathsf{C}$.  The origin of co-ordinates is defined to be on that free surface, so the absolute head at $\mathsf{C}$ is zero.